# Reactjs, prevent flickering of parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **react** project, the parent component connects to **redux** store, takes image urls and pass the set to a child component via *props*, lets say image collection.

The child component takes them and loads first image from props, when a button in child component is clicked, the seccond image gets loaded.

When i click those buttons, only child component state gets re-rendered (confirmed in console logs), but I can find that entire parent components flickers while the child component change image.

Comment: can you provide minimal example to play around it?